# How to hide all command output with zsh and bash

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

**How can I hide all output that is written and outputted in a terminal?**

In other words, I am looking to add the string

```
>/dev/null 2&>1
```

to every command I write.

- How would you do it with bash?
- How would you do it with zsh?
- Ideally how to have a configuration that take into account any terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `zsh`:

You can redirect stdout and stderr of any following command to `/dev/null` by running these two command:

```
exec >/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
```

**Note**: This will still show the prompt and anything you type on the command line, but not much else.

### `bash`:

You can redirect stdout and stderr with the following command

```
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Note**

- This may suppress any output, including the prompt and what you type on the command line. (This was the case for me with `zsh` 5.2 and `bash` 4.4, when I first created this answer in 2016. While it seems to still be the case with `bash` 5.1.8, it looks like with `zsh` this is no longer the case since at least version 5.8)
- To enable the output again, run

  ```
    exec >/dev/tty
    exec 2>/dev/tty
  ```

Comment: this doesn’t appear to work with Zsh’s `builtin >/dev/null 2>&1` or with `builtin does_not_exist >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Lucas I just checked with my zsh (5.8) and curiously `builtin nx >/dev/null 2>&1` does indeed still produce a "no such builtin" error message, while running `nx >/dev/null 2>&1`  does suppress the "command not found" error. But running `exec 2>/dev/null` beforehand does suppress any error messages thereafter, including those of `builtin nx` (at least on my machine). Running `builtin` without any arguments does not produce any output for me anyway, with or without redirections. And when running for example `builtin pwd >/dev/null 2>&1` the output looks to be suppressed as expected.